# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid Hiding the First column in between values

Tags: oracle-apex

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omn6i.png)

Good Day Everyone!

I'm working in oracle apex in which I have linked to interactive grids the top grid is my parent and the below is my child grid but the issue I'm facing right now is that child grid is showing is hiding my first column in between values any just showing me the first and the last value of first column. But if I drag this column in last place all the records are visible, it's not a view error I also change the column alignment but apex hiding my first column value and if I place there any display item it will hide the second column value same as first column any suggestion why is this unusual error occurs.

I just want to see the values because if I want to do any DML operation it goes into error, because there is undefine values of there!

Comment: Can you please support your problem with visuals, images etc. so that we unnderstand the issue better and help you.

Comment: What version of apex are you on ? You have tagged multiple versions, only "oracle-apex" should do.

Comment: I'm working on oracle apex version 23.1